# How to get ref of DOM element which is not present in DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need to get ref from renderElement method but getting current of null. Suggest me a better approach to resolve this.

````
export default class ReactTest extends Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.inviteRef = null;
  this.state = {};
}

renderElement = ()=> {
 this.inviteRef = React.createRef();
  return(
   <div ref={this.inviteRef}></div>
 )
}

  render() {  
    const {currentPage} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="dummy"> 
      {currentPage === 0 ? this.renderElement : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: When you open the console do you get `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.` or did you post code in the question that does not [demonstrate the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you are having?

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you a ref if the element is rendered. You can't get a ref to an element that isn't rendered. Not sure why you don't make `renderElement` into it's own component.

You forgot to call `renderElement` so it is never called and won't render a thing no matter what currentPage is.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inviteRef = null;
    this.state = { currentPage: 0 };
  }

  renderElement = () => {
    this.inviteRef = React.createRef();
    return <div ref={this.inviteRef}>render element</div>;
  };
  buttonClick = () => {
    console.log('ref is:', this.inviteRef.current);
  };
  unrender = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: this.state.currentPage === 0 ? 1 : 0,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dummy">
        <button onClick={this.buttonClick}>
          what is ref?
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.unrender}>
          toggle renderElement
        </button>
        {this.state.currentPage === 0
          ? this.renderElement() //you have to call it, its a function
          : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```